# How to change Java Swing JScrollPane mouse wheel priority to horizontal scrolling?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I can see right now the scrolling priority is given to vertical scrolling. I want to change that. How do I do that?

Comment: for JTextComponents, JList or JTable or ...., (in this form) this question isn't answerable

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the first answer- very helpful. However I found that iNewValue  in the response above needs to be multiplied by the evt.getWheelRotation() value which is the number of distinct wheel mouse segments actually rotated by the wheel mouse.

Also the condition of when to scroll needs to take account of this as well - the condition has to be evt.getWheelRotation() <= -1 or evt.getWheelRotation() >= 1

Here is an  updated example that worked for me.

```
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
    import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    class MyJScrollPane extends JScrollPane 
    {



        public MyJScrollPane(Component component)
        {
            super(component);
            final JScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = getHorizontalScrollBar();
            final JScrollBar verticalScrollBar = getVerticalScrollBar();
            setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);
            addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent evt)
                {

                    if (evt.getWheelRotation() >= 1)//mouse wheel was rotated down/ towards the user
                    {
                        int iScrollAmount = evt.getScrollAmount();
                        int iNewValue = horizontalScrollBar.getValue() + horizontalScrollBar.getBlockIncrement() * iScrollAmount * Math.abs(evt.getWheelRotation());
                        if (iNewValue <= horizontalScrollBar.getMaximum())
                        {
                            horizontalScrollBar.setValue(iNewValue);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (evt.getWheelRotation() <= -1)//mouse wheel was rotated up/away from the user
                    {
                        int iScrollAmount = evt.getScrollAmount();
                        int iNewValue = horizontalScrollBar.getValue() - horizontalScrollBar.getBlockIncrement() * iScrollAmount * Math.abs(evt.getWheelRotation());
                        if (iNewValue >= 0)
                        {
                            horizontalScrollBar.setValue(iNewValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: This version may need a tweak using max/min to reach the maximum when the `if` condition is false (when it would overshoot).  The earlier answer that didn't scale the scroll speed was ok in that regard because min/max are integer and it only moved by +-1.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default scrolling priority of the `JScrollPane` you need to create your own version of `JScrollPane` and when mouse Wheel is moved enforce the horizontal `ScrollBar` to come in action instead of vertical `ScrollBar`.

The overridden version of JScrollPane can be created like this:

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;

class MyJScrollPane extends JScrollPane 
{
    public MyJScrollPane(Component component)
    {
        super(component);
        final JScrollBar horizontalScrollBar = getHorizontalScrollBar();
        final JScrollBar verticalScrollBar = getVerticalScrollBar();
        setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);
        addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent evt)
            {
                if (evt.getWheelRotation() == 1)//mouse wheel was rotated down/ towards the user
                {
                    int iScrollAmount = evt.getScrollAmount();
                    int iNewValue = horizontalScrollBar.getValue() + horizontalScrollBar.getBlockIncrement() * iScrollAmount;
                    if (iNewValue <= horizontalScrollBar.getMaximum())
                    {
                        horizontalScrollBar.setValue(iNewValue);
                    }
                }
                else if (evt.getWheelRotation() == -1)//mouse wheel was rotated up/away from the user
                {
                    int iScrollAmount = evt.getScrollAmount();
                    int iNewValue = horizontalScrollBar.getValue() - horizontalScrollBar.getBlockIncrement() * iScrollAmount;
                    if (iNewValue >= 0)
                    {
                        horizontalScrollBar.setValue(iNewValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I Hope this solves your problem of scrolling priority of `JScrollPane`.