# Detecting Horizontal Mouse Wheel movement in java

Tags: java, swing, button, mouse, listener

Is there any particular reason why Java cannot detect those two buttons?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oggsj.png


I have wrote a simple class to check for those buttons.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Horizontal_wheel_button_test
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        JFrame okno = new JFrame ();
        okno.setSize (800, 600);
        okno.setVisible (true);
        okno.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        okno.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        okno.addMouseListener (new MouseListener ()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println (e);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println (e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When i press standard buttons, Listener reacts, giving me number of buttons from 1 to 3, but when I press the wheel to the left and to the right, it is not able to notify those events. Is it because Java does not support those buttons or maybe it's because of my OS (Windows 7)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464228/how-to-change-java-swing-jscrollpane-mouse-wheel-priority-to-horizontal-scrollin

Comment: you ask for a horizontal detection and you code can not even detect a vertical movement of the wheel...so its obvious that there must be another listener for the wheel.

Comment: It's not about detecting mouse wheel scrolling (which how to do). I want to detect when i'm pressing mouse from left and right, which should be accessible through MouseListener which detects when I am pressing wheel from top.

Comment: Left/rigt wheel tumble gives me button numbers 4 and 5. My mouse's forward/backward buttons give me button numbers 6 and 7. (Ubuntu here)